# MySQL date precision

Tags: mysql, date

I have this on my `WHERE` clause

```
dob <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND dob >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 19 YEAR)
```

It works alright,it searches a persons by age based on their DOB,
however there is some precision issues.

Consider the following:

```
1 to 19                                 =             397
20-25                                   =            1350
26- 30                                  =            1139
31-35                                   =             601
36-40                                   =             346
41-45                                   =             218
46- 50                                  =             154
51-55                                   =             139
56-60                                   =              65
61-85                                   =              78      Total = 4487
```

If I use the same method but search for 1 - 85 return **5607**

I am puzzled but then again dates are my weakness so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, I think when you do `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 19 YEAR)` and then `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 20 YEAR)`

You miss people in there 19th years, so you're missing the people in there 19th, 26th, 30th, 35th ... etc

It should be 
`dob < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND dob >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 19 YEAR)`

And then
`dob < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 19 YEAR) AND dob >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 25 YEAR)`

edit :

```
 1  to 19                                   =            ??
 19 to 25                                   =            ??
 25 to 30                                   =            ??
 30 to 35                                   =            ??
 35 to 40                                   =            ??
 40 to 45                                   =            ??
 45 to 50                                   =            ??
 50 to 55                                   =            ?? 
 55 to 60                                   =            ??
 60 to 85                                   =            ??`
```

Comment: that is like the between function but inclusive of the date range

Comment: Nope I used order by to check the list and the age is correct.

Comment: `<=` and `>=` makes the search inclusive doesn't it?

Comment: For example, `DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 19 YEAR ) == '1992-08-08'` but `DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 20 YEAR ) == '1991-08-08'` -- you're skipping people who are born between those dates. Note that `DATE_SUB()` returns a date, not a year.

Comment: `<= and >=` makes the search inclusive of course but see @juhana comment

Comment: That has backfired, I got `3481` and `2019` for `26-30` and `20-25` respectively, Im starting to question if it's invert searching

Comment: My understanding is that all the equal does, is inclusive even if their birthday is today, it shouldn't affect a whole year and I doubt there 1 in 10 ppl (approximately) have the dob today :)

Comment: I think I might have to make the max age +1 so it fixes the problem right?

Comment: You should do (@see edited answer) and put your lower bound exclusive so you won't have people having there birthday on the bound date today.